# How can I make QtCreator generate ui header files automatically without having to compile the project?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

It's possibly a duplicate, but I couldn't find a related question here.

I've been wondering if there's a way to make QtCreator generate ui header files (`ui_{class_name}.h`) without having to compile the whole project.

I know those files are generated by uic tool, but if I go to Projects -> Build settings, I see no commands related to using that tool (even though it seems to be used, since header files are generated once I recompile the project).

It would be convinient for me if header files were generated once I edit my `.ui` files.
Can I get that kind of behaviour from QtCreator? If I got something wrong, any help on clarifying this process is appreciated!

Comment: These files are generated not by uic tool, but by moc tool. If you use qmake and open the generated Makefile (you can trigger it generation by Build-> Run qmake) you'll find scripts dealing with moc'ing.